# Error Facebook Connector with Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-social-connected

Step 1:

I created one app in face book with category "Apps For Pages"

[image]

Step 2:
And also enabled client OAuth Login

[image]

Step 3:

Created face book connector in site core with already created in facebook app details.

[image]

Step 4:
Added login with face book control to my "index" item.

[image]

Step 5:

Used the face book connector (step 3) as data source.

[image]

Step 6:

[image]

click the face book button ,getting following error.

[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: You may want to update the image for step 3 as you have exposed your App Id and your Secret there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top image - you haven't filled out the `App Domains` data. That seems to be what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks  Richard, I filled app domain and website url, but still am getting same error.

Comment: Now working, and also disable the user_interests in Sitecore.Social.ProfileMapping.Facebook.config file See below Setting: <field enabled="false" originalKey="" sitecoreKey="fb_interests" permission="user_interests" access="/me/interests" text="Interests" />